# Converting XML to formatted text vial XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, text

I'm completely new to the game. The project I'm working on needs to be able to alternately render to either html or text.  I decided to try XSLT's so I could modify the output without really changing the underlying code structure.  HTML output is fine.  Getting a little lost in trying to write a transform to text.   Here's why:

The xml I'm transforming is within this type of structure:

```
<Data>
  <Text x="0" y="1">First Line</Text>
  <Text x="12" y="1">Continued on Same Line</Text>
  <Text x="36" y="1">Still Going</Text>
  <Text x="5" y="2">Slightly Indented New Line</Text>
</Data>
```

The basic template I'm using for html is working fine.  I am trying now to create a template for a text output, ie

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

but am as of yet unable to devise a way to build strings from Text elements based on "x" and "y" values (or coordinates), which is what I need to do for the text output such that what writes to the text file from the sample xml above is:

```
First Line Continued on Same Line Still Going
    Slightly Indented New Line
```

So, if I were to do the equivalent in code, it might look like:

```
private string SomeMethod(XPathNavigator TestNav)
{
int iRow = 0;
int iColumn = 0;
XPathNodeIterator lineIterator = TestNav.SelectChildren("Data", "");
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while (lineIterator.MoveNext())
{

 XPathNavigator curNav= lineIterator.Current;
 XPathExpression Exp = curNav.Compile("*[@x]|*/*[@x]");
 Exp.AddSort("@y", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);
 Exp.AddSort("@x", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);
 XPathNodeIterator positionIterator = curNav.Select(Exp);
 while (positionIterator.MoveNext())
     {                        
         String elValue = positionIterator.Current.InnerXml;
         int xTxt = int.Parse(positionIterator.Current.GetAttribute("x", ""));
         int yTxt = int.Parse(positionIterator.Current.GetAttribute("y", ""));

             if (iRow < yTxt)
             {
                string newLines = new string('\n', yTxt - iRow);
                text = text.Append(newLines);
                iColumn = 0;
             }

             if (iColumn < xTxt)
             {
                 string newLines = new string(' ', xTxt - iColumn);
                 text = text.Append(newLines);
             }

             text = text.Append(elValue);

             iRow = yTxt;
             iColumn = xTxt + elValue.Length;
      }

      if (lineIterator.Count != 0)
      {
         text = text.Append("\n\f\n");
         iRow = 0;
         iColumn = 0;
      }
}            
        return text.ToString();
}
```

Given the structure of the above xml, any ideas how I could go about doing the same thing in an XSLT, once again with the output method set to text so it persists to file so that complete lines are built from the x and y coordinates of the individual words.  So, if for two words, "Hello World" they are represented as

```
<Text x="0" y="1">Hello</Text>
<Text x="6" y="1">World</Text>
```

Then "Hello" instantiates a string, and consumes 5 characters of space, 0-4.  "World" starts at 6, so character index "5" is filled with white space (and would continue to do so until the next highest x attribute is reached).  The next highest x attribute in a 'Text' element with the same y attribute is "6".  So it's value is then appended to the existing string.  Same logic for y values.

Please let me know if this isn't clear enough, I'll happily explain more, or differently.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want from the text output?  It sounds like you need different modes for HTML and text, as they have different requirements.

Comment: Yes, exactly right.  I'll modify the post to reflect clarification.

Comment: So you actually want "co-ordinate" positioning of all the individual bits in text mode?

Comment: Well, that's the dream at least.  I'm way new in xsl though, and am just not sure of the complexity required in pursuing this further.  Each coordinate will never represent less than a word, but I don't suppose that really makes a difference since whitespace is expected in the output, but not given in the xml unless it appears between words.

Comment: XSLT is not the best tool to do this. It is possible to build a stylesheet that does all the necessary calculations and outputs correctly formatted plain text, but the result would be hopelessly complicated. Think about doing this in C# directly - It would be easy there to have a list of strings/buffers, allowing you to write randomly at defined positions as you go through the XML. XSLT has not been designed for that kind of work.

Comment: The more I dug in the more I started to realize that.  Just thought I'd try an see what others thought first though since I am new to it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Are the dimensions of the x-y grid known? IOW, is there a maximum of line-length and/or a maximum of number of lines?

Comment: @Joe Look at my modified answer to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The dimensions of the grid in which the text will be placed (ultimately) is not known.  However, there will never be line or page overrun because of higher level controls on incoming data.  So as long as the 'x' and 'y' relative positions are honored, all should be well.

Comment: @Tomalak I see what you mean by involved.  I wrote that sample on the fly, the real data won't give conflicting coordinate locations.  However, you're right, it's quite involved.  I posted because the xml to web with xsl is so simple, and I only ever need to render to html or text, I though it would be really convenient to design both types of render to simply call the transform, and simply modify the stream that it wrote to.  Thank you so much for all the samples, I've learned tons on xsl simply by reading your replies.  Thanks to everyone that took the time to reply to this.

Comment: It may be that your input data does not contain overlaps, but they're technically possible, so the program must deal with them in some way. Of course you can remove that additional logic and save a few lines (and some complexity). In fact I did not think the solution would become that "simple", so if you're comfortable with it... You would need two separate stylesheets anyway, one that transforms to *ML and one that transforms to plain text. You could share functions between them using `<xsl:include>`, if necessary. I'm willing to help debug it if needed,  just post a larger XML sample.

Comment: Oh excellent.  Will do.  It will be a few days unfortunately before I'm able.  But thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated than it seems.

- You must group `<Text>` items by `@y`. All with the same `@y` value are on the same line.
- You must decide whether you want to represent empty/missing lines (i.e. non-consecutive `@y` values) or not. Not representing them is simpler.
- You must decide whether you just want to concatenate everything that shares the same line or arrange it by the respective `@x` values individually. The latter is considerably more complicated.
- As a minimum you can prefix the first item on every line by the amount of `@x` that was defined.

This XSLT transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="kLine" match="Text" use="@y" />
  <xsl:variable name="padding" select="'                                     '"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Text[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLine', @y))]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kLine', @y)">
        <xsl:sort select="@x" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLine', @y))">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($padding, 1, @x)" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives with your input

```
First Line Continued on Same Line Still Going
     Slightly Indented New Line
```

The notable technique used here is called Muenchian grouping.

---

FWIW, here is a solution that does what you request. Decide for yourself if it's worth the trouble.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="kLine" match="Text" use="@y" />
  <xsl:variable name="padX" select="'                                     '"/>
  <xsl:variable name="padY" select="'&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Text[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLine', @y))]">
      <xsl:sort select="@y" data-type="number" />

      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kLine', @y)">
        <xsl:sort select="@x" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <!-- find the vertical position of the logically following text -->
      <xsl:variable name="nextY">
        <xsl:for-each select="../Text[@y &gt; current()/@y]">
          <xsl:sort select="@y" data-type="number" />
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="@y" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($padY, 1, $nextY - @y)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Text">
    <!-- indent first item on line -->
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLine', @y))">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($padX, 1, @x)" />
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:variable name="text" select="normalize-space()" />

    <!-- calculate the available text block width -->
    <xsl:variable name="width">
      <!-- find the horizontal position of the logically following text -->
      <xsl:variable name="nextX">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kLine', @y)[@x &gt; current()/@x]">
          <xsl:sort select="@x" data-type="number" />
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="@x" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nextX &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$nextX - @x - 1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="string-length($text)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- current text + necessary right padding for next item -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($text, $padX), 1, $width)" />

    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

used on this:

```
<Data>
  <Text x="0" y="1">First Line</Text>
  <Text x="20" y="1">Continued on Same Line</Text>
  <Text x="42" y="1">Still Going</Text>
  <Text x="4" y="5">Slightly Indented New Line</Text>
  <Text x="30" y="3">30 spaces before this</Text>
</Data>
```

gives (line an grid numbers added for convenience):

```
 |         1         2         3         4         5
 |    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5
-+-------------------------------------------------------
1|First Line          Continued on Same Lin Still Going
2|
3|                              30 spaces before this
4|
5|   Slightly Indented New Line
```

Note how it cuts out text that would not fit. Also, this is not thoroughly tested, it's just a proof-of concept. It may behave all kinds of funny on your input.

Also note that you have to decide whether you want to use a 1-based (like with `@y`) or a 0-based (like with `@x`) co-ordindate system. Currently it's not consistent in your sample input.